# Error: ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION evaluation (a DATE,m Number)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
RETURN CASE
WHEN (floor(sysdate - a) < m) THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'No'
END;
```

Am i doing wrongly, when executing the following  code if shows me an error like:

```
Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Comment: Can you show us how you *call* that function? (the exact values)

Comment: No sorry, while compiling itself it pulls me this error..

Comment: That error will not be thrown when you compile this procedure: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/65380/1

Answer (score 4):

The posted code is missing an `END;` (the first `END` ends the `CASE`, so a second is needed to end the procedure), but other than that it is working, provided you enter a number and not a string that cannot be converted to a number.

```
select evaluation(sysdate+3, 2) from dual;

YES

select evaluation(sysdate+3, '2') from dual;

YES

select evaluation(sysdate+3, 'a') from dual;

Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Answer (score 0):

Include another end @ last.....

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION evaluation (a DATE,m Number)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
RETURN (CASE
WHEN (floor(sysdate - a) < m) THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'No'
END);
END;
```